# PHP session expire after the Yahoo API call?

Tags: session-variables, yahoo, yahoo-api, php

In my Website,

I am building the Yahoo API application.

When ever we access the Yahoo API from our application,

The Yahoo returns the success response to our domain.But my custom session values has expired.

I don't know the reason.

Any help my appreciation.

Comment: Please post some code. Maybe you're not saving/loading the session correctly, could be a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code I would have to speculate that your $_SESSION['?'] is either being unset:

```
unset($_SESSION['?']);
```

or is being destroyed:

```
session_destroy();
```

somewhere in your application. Check to see that you are not doing these things in your application.